# SolanaJSONRPCError: failed to get confirmed block: Block not available for slot

Tags: web3.js

I am new to Sol web3 dev. I am trying to get pending transactions of a wallet. When I try to get the block, it fails with error "SolanaJSONRPCError: failed to get confirmed block: Block not available for slot " Could somebody help me? Here is my code snippet and it fails at getBlock or getConfirmedBlock methods.

const connection = new Connection('https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com'); // Use the appropriate network

async function copyPendingTrades() {
// Subscribe to new blocks
const subscription = connection.onSlotChange(async (slotInfo) => {
// Fetch all transactions in the latest block
const blockhash = await connection.getRecentBlockhash();
const confirmedTransactions = await connection.getConfirmedBlock(slotInfo.slot);
const unconfirmedTransactions = await connection.getBlock(slotInfo.slot);

```
// Extract unconfirmed transactions
const pendingTransactions = unconfirmedTransactions.transactions.filter(
  (tx) => !confirmedTransactions.transactions.some((confirmedTx) => confirmedTx.transaction.signature === tx.transaction.signature)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things to clarify here.

The error `Block not available for slot` is happening because you're querying the block with `getBlock` before it's been confirmed. Only confirmed blocks are available with `getBlock`.

In fact, it is impossible to query information about unconfirmed transactions through `getBlock`. If you want to check on the confirmation status of a transaction, you need to know its signature and then use `connection.confirmTransaction` with that signature to see if it's been confirmed.

There's no concept of "pending transactions" that can be queried, unless you run some external service that holds this information in a database.